# Setting up HUAWEI E173 for Broadband by using sakis3g returns "ERROR" for PIN

Tags: 16.04, mobile-broadband, huawei

I am in Sri Lanka and the cheapest way to connect to the internet is by using broadband. I bought a Huawei E173 and a sim-card from dialog with internet. I checked and it's all set up properly.

When I connect the stick with my computer (Ubuntu 16.04, Lenovo T460) it is recognised, lsusb returns the following:

```
lukas@eumelkiste-ultimate:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b52c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I get a automated message from my network-manager that I am now registered on the home network( or something along that line), I also installed modem-manager-gui which recognized the device and showed me the received sms. I first followed the following website to connect to the broadband: [Website](http://mobilebroadband.gishan.net/entry/58/how-to-setup-broadband-dongle-in-ubuntu), however it didn't work, I tried all the APN-options just to be on the safe side, it didn't work.

So i came across this [website](http://geeklk.com/2013/02/22/prolink-phs300-dongle-on-ubuntu/), which suggested sakis3g. Well I installed it according to the website and started it. It would recognize my device, but if I click on the detected usb-device I got at first: "Modem responded "ERROR" while checking for PIN." I restarted and checked again, I would get:
Gerät meldet keine GSM-Verbindungen. Sie können dies durch Hinzufügen des --noprobe Kommandozeilenschalters überspringen. (which means something along the device does not report GSM-connections, you can ignore this with the --noprobe command), which I did (sakis3g --noprobe), but it would give me the ERROR promt again.

EDID: The post [HUAWEI E173 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179324/huawei-e173-on-ubuntu-12-04) is not the solution, whilst related, the author had no idea what to do after plugging in the device. The steps described in the answer (Set up a Broadband-Connection with the network-manager) did not connect me to the broadband as stated above already

I didn't get any good google-results after this, I read something along the line that the device might be not in "modem-mode"? However no good help how to switch this. I am really at my wits end, I hope somebody has a idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HUAWEI E173 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179324/huawei-e173-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: This is not true, the problem there was, that the stick was not in a USB3 port and/or the device is not recognized. Which is not the case for me

Comment: I just found out how to switch the modem-mode, but appently the device already in modem mode and working fine. I am really lost here :(.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that bug. This is a recent bug in 16.04. I have not been able to solve it myself. Anyhow, many questions already exist: http://askubuntu.com/questions/790893/huawei-usb-4g-modem-not-detected.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/788908/ubuntu-16-04-mobile-broadband-usb-stick-sometimes-not-detected-at-all. http://askubuntu.com/questions/833704/mobile-partner-for-ubuntu-16-04.