# mobile partner for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, huawei

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` with `Huawei` mobile broadband dongle and I need a software like `mobile partner` which is available in `Windows` to use in `Ubuntu` environment. I have installed `Modem manager GUI` but though it provides all the services, it is cannot be used to connect and disconnect to the Internet ( as it does not provide that service). I read through many answers given on how to install mobile partner in ubuntu like the one in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323396/how-to-install-huawei-mobile-partner-21-in-ubuntu) ( the 64bit download link is not working) and others are not up to date to be used in `16.04`. Can anybody show me how to install `Huawei` mobile partner in ubuntu `16.04`
Thanks in advance