# Huawei E3372 XUbuntu

Tags: networking, usb, xubuntu, usb-modem

I have a problem with Huawei E3372 modem.

Xubuntu 18.04.2 LTS did not detect it as a mobile broadband modem. 
E3372 is not detected.

I have checked lsusb, and here I can see the system detects it as 
12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
but I cannot choose it in my Network Connections.
It displays Mobile Broadband not enabled.

I have  added

## Huawei E3372

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1506", RUN +="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

in /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules.

I followed the steps in the posts

[Huawei E3272 Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525965/huawei-e3272-ubuntu)
and
[Huawei usb 4G modem not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790893/huawei-usb-4g-modem-not-detected)

but in vain

configPack.tar.gz does not contain 12d1:1506. hence the following command

```
tar xf /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz 12d1\:1506
```

didn't worked. Hence I followed the same code in the post

```
tar xf /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz 12d1\:14fe
```

and went to the folder /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/

```
cp 12d1:14fe 12d1:1506
```

and added the line in the following file

add line to file /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1506", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

Still it didn't work.

Again tried, added the following to the file /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14fe", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

Nothing worked so far.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

nmcli d

```
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp2s0   wifi      disconnected  --         
enp3s0   ethernet  unmanaged     --         
ttyUSB0  gsm       unmanaged     --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged     --
```

lsmod | grep cdc

```
huawei_cdc_ncm         16384  0
cdc_wdm                20480  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
cdc_ncm                36864  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
usbnet                 45056  2 cdc_ncm,huawei_cdc_ncm
```

Comment: can you show `nmcli d` and `lsmod | grep cdc` please.

Comment: @nobody
nmcli d
    DEVICE   TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
    wlp2s0   wifi      disconnected  --         
    enp3s0   ethernet  unmanaged     --         
    ttyUSB0  gsm       unmanaged     --         
    lo       loopback  unmanaged     --    

lsmod | grep cdc
    huawei_cdc_ncm         16384  0
    cdc_wdm                20480  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
    cdc_ncm                36864  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
    usbnet                 45056  2 cdc_ncm,huawei_cdc_ncm

Comment: Here `ttyUSB0  gsm` is your modem.  `nmcli general status` please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, that works for both 16.04 and 18.04.

None of the above steps are necessary.

I have just purchased a Huawei E3372H, so I can save you 2 hours of time wasted on scouring your system and writing new udev rules and usb_modeswitch configurations (which is what I did, LOL).

The E3372 **does not** show up as a mobile broadband device. It shows up as an ethernet device in the Network Connections Manager: e.g. 'Ethernet Network (HUAWEI MOBILE)'.

Users may want to disable the 'Autoconnect' option in the 'General' tab of the connections editor, otherwise a connection will be automatically made upon boot-up/log-in.

Note, when disconneted in the network manager, the dongle light will still appear to be connected. This can be positively switched off by going to the router url (find it in network manager, Connection Information, **Default Route** (e.g. 192.168.1.1)) in your web-browser, and clicking on 'Disable Mobile Data'.

Comment: What is the solution?  I suggest that you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1307104/edit) your answer.  Lead with the solution.  You don't need to tell us what doesn't work: this only makes your solution confusing.  Some of the best answers on Ask Ubuntu give clear step-by-step directions explaining how to solve the problem and they leave out extra information that isn't needed to explain the answer.  Please note that we use a Q&A format so when you reference content "above" you it makes no sense.  You should try to write your answer as if it's the only one.